# Rate of Decline Excel

Tags: excel

I have a set of dates and count of values and want to know at what overall rate are they declining. If I graph the date I can see the downward trend. I do not want the % change from the the first date to the last but the rate at which it is decreasing overall.

```
8/1/23 192
8/2/23 199
8/3/23 235
8/4/23 180
8/5/23 178
8/6/23 201
8/7/23 154
8/8/23 195
8/9/23 164
8/10/23 178
8/11/23 161
```

Comment: You want the *slope* of the graph. A search for "excel chart get slope" will yield useful results.

Comment: Watch this video: [How to find the trend line equation using Excel.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxMX6tGxYWk)

Comment: When I tried it, it shows `y=-4.0545x+183224` for the equation.  The 183224 is the starting date converted to a number.  Basically, -4.0545*{number of days}, or, for example -4.0545*10 would mean a drop of 40.545.  You start out with the value of 200, so 200/4.0545 is 49.32 days.  If we multiply the -4.0545 per day by 49.32 days we get a drop of 199.96794.  This means your supply of 200 items will run out in approximately 49.32 days.